# remove unwanted space in font - css

Tags: css

I am facing a stupid issue in showing text on website.
Please see the attached image [image].

I have drawn the red line on left side of this text, but there is a clear space between "T" and "1", when it changes to "2", space issue resolved.
I have tried the different fonts but issue still occurs.

Now, here is the image of win10 screen lock

[image]

I am using these fonts

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Now, you can see there is no gap between "1" and "F". any one know how can i solve this one ?

Comment: In that font, number 1's width is smaller than that of number 2. You could use a monospace font.

Comment: yes, monospace is what  I need. thanks for suggesting

Comment: You can also play with `letter-spacing`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [CSS `text-indent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent). It helps provide positive or negative indentation at the beginning of a new block of text. However, if you provide negative indentation so it looks good on narrow numbers, like a `1`, it will stick out on wide numbers, like a `5`.

A combination of `text-indent` with [a monospace font](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace) should resolve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Do not rely on system fonts.
Consider using a web-font.
You can find one with proper glyphs:

```css
body {background: #000; color: #fff; font: 300 2rem/1 'Barlow', sans-serif}

h1, p
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-left: solid 2px red;
}

p {
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow:300" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>11:40</h1>
<p>Thursday, June 21</p>
<h1>01:40</h1>
```